# Invoke parameter from another method

Tags: c#

I need to invoke the `callback` action from within `ResponseReceived` handler.
If there's a better way, I am very open.

`Connection` and `IDriver` are from different assemblies. Trying to make them work together.

```
class Test : IDriver
{
    private Connection _connection;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _connection = new Connection(new ResponseCallback(ResponseReceived));
    }

    public void Begin(Action<OperationResponse> callback)
    {
        _connection.SendRequest();
    }

    private static void ResponseReceived(object source, MessageReceivedArgs e)
    {
        // Need to invoke `callback` parameter of Begin from here.
    }
```

Comment: This design seems very fragile. Having a method rely on the calling of a previous one seems to me like a bad idea. Why do you need this structure?

Comment: I have updated the text a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the passed in `Action<OperationResponse>` instance to a private field for later use.

Also I removed the `static` keyword on `ResponseReceived`. You can't access instance variables from a static method. If you did want it static you would have to pass in an instance of `Test` as well (maybe that is `source` in which case you could cast it back to `Test` to get the `_callback` instance)?

```
class Test : IDriver
{
    private Connection _connection;
    private Action<OperationResponse> _callback;
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _connection = new Connection(new ResponseCallback(ResponseReceived));
    }

    public void Begin(Action<OperationResponse> callback)
    {
        _connection.SendRequest();
        _callback = callback;
    }

    private void ResponseReceived(object source, MessageReceivedArgs e)
    {
        _callback(responseInstanceHere);
    }
```

#### Points of contention

- What do you want to happen if Begin is called multiple times with different callbacks before the callback has occurred? Options include:

  - Use the latest or first callback passed in
  - Throw an exception
- What do you want to happen if `ResponseReceived` is called before Begin? Is this even possible? Should the null callback throw an NRE or should it just be ignored?
- Can an instance be reused? Should you clear the callback after it has had at least one call?

In short your code could use some error checking and useful Exceptions where applicable. I am not going to add them because I do not know the use context of this type.

Comment: This will now error if you call `ResponseReceived` before `Begin`. I'd add a null check and throw a useful error

Comment: TBH in general having one method rely on the previous calling of another seems fragile at best

Comment: And the Begin() method must throw an InvalidOperationException when the variable isn't null.

Comment: @Liam - I would prefer an exception, it would let you know right away that the code is wrong instead of waiting for a callback that never occurs. But which one is more correct is up for debate and could also depend on context.

Comment: IMO I'd prefer a useful exception not just a random Object reference one, something like `throw new Exception("_callback is null, you must call Begin before ResponseReceived");`

Comment: @Liam I have added some verbiage about what could be added  for error checking.

Comment: @HansPassant - fair enough, I have added some verbiage about possible invalid state and error checking.